# Spring mvc controller jsr 303 basic list validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have a simple MVC controller that takes a list of emails, and will then send a message to those emails.

### json POST body

```
{"emailAddresses" : []}
```

### code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/share", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void shareThing(@PathVariable(value = "id") final String id, @Valid @NotEmpty       @RequestBody  final List<String> emailAddresses)
```

Basically, I want to use jsr-303 so that if the client posts a request with no emails, it fails. Preferably with a 401.

Should the above code work? Or what do I need to do? Here's the setup. Hibernate validator is on the classpath, so it should be picking up. However if I post an empty json array, it goes straight into the method with an empty array list as the bound parameter.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.package.thing"})
public class WeConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

### json POST body

```
{"emailAddresses" : []}
```

### code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/share", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void shareThing(@PathVariable(value = "id") final String id, @Valid @NotEmpty          @RequestBody  final List<String> emailAddresses, BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    System.out.println("Has Errors? " + bindingResult.hasErrors();
}
```

### output

Has Errors? false

### trial 3, changing payload, works... but I don't see the need to wrap?

```
public class EmailListDTO {

@NotEmpty
private List<String> emailAddresses;

public List<String> getEmailAddresses() {
    return emailAddresses;
}

public void setEmailAddresses(List<String> emailAddresses) {
    this.emailAddresses = emailAddresses;
}
```

}

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/share", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void shareThing(@PathVariable(value = "id") final String id, @Valid             @RequestBody  EmailListDTO emailListDTO, BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    System.out.println("Has Errors? " + bindingResult.hasErrors();
}
```

### json POST body

```
{"emailAddresses" : []}
```

### output

Has Errors? true

Comment: only thing in the body is a json array. POST request. set content type to application/json. It works when there are values and populates the list -- it is parsing it correctly as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Valid` validates if the parameter class type itself has `javax.validation` annotations on fields. So it would use the `Validator` to scan the `List` class for validation annotations, which is not what you want.

You should wrap your `List<String>` into a DTO and change your parameter to that

```
public class MyListDTO {
    @NotEmpty 
    private List<String> emailAddresses;
    ... //getters and setters
}
```

`@Valid` doesn't just make it fail, it binds the error to a `BindingResult` object. If you add add a `BindingResult` parameter to your handler method (it must be next to your `@Valid` parameter)

```
 public void shareThing(@PathVariable(value = "id") final String id, @Valid @RequestBody final MyListDTO myDTO, BindingResult errors )
```

you can then checks the `BindingResult` for errors and choose what to do.

Comment: Still not working for me. Added update. Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: @Matt Yes, I'm missing something. Give me a sec.

Comment: @Matt See my edit. Wrap your `List` in a class that contains the `javax.validation` annotation you want to use.

Comment: Ok, this works as per edit. But goodness this is overkill imo. I don't need an entire dto, i don't want to have to wrap a list in a json object like so : {"emailAddresses" : []} . any way around that?

Comment: @Matt The workaround is more overkill :) Spring uses this interface called `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to provide arguments your your handler methods. You would have to create and register your custom resolver. This way, even though it's overkill, is the only default way to do it.

Comment: are you saying there's a way for me to register a custom resolver for "validate this list of strings isn't empty, and if it is kick out a 401" ? Because that would be worth it to me (and I would imagine others)

Comment: The whole 401 you can do in the controller itself. The validation, you could make a custom resolver, but it is not worth it in this case. Make a DTO.  If you really want to, look up the interface and check the DispatcherServlet stack to see where it comes into play.